# How do I get the OIC token in Wildfly 26?

Tags: single-sign-on, wildfly, keycloak, wildfly-26

Migrating from Wildfly 18 + Keycloack adapter, to Wildfly 26 w/ build-in OIC support.

Previously, to allow Sign-Out (I mean really Signing out from Keycloack, not just invalidating the session) I fetched the token from the session attributes and added to the logout URL (see below. That was tied to wildfly server, but it worked).

How do I get the OIC token in Wildfly 26 ?

```
org.keycloak.KeycloakSecurityContext securityContext = (org.keycloak.KeycloakSecurityContext) request.getAttribute(KeycloakSecurityContext.class.getName()); 
String token = securityContext.getIdTokenString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it,
use `org.wildfly.security.http.oidc.OidcSecurityContext`

instead of `wildfly-elytron-http-oidc-1.19.0.Final.jar`